# How can I render Bokeh Plots with Widgets in Data Spyre?

Tags: python, cherrypy, bokeh

I'm using python's Data Spyre to create a simple web application to expose some data and plots, and I wanted to leverage some of Bokeh's widgets in it as well. I've been able to include Bokeh plots successfully, but as soon as I added the MultiSelect tool I've been getting the following error:

```
(index):10137 Uncaught Error: Module `MultiSelect' does not exists. The problem may be two fold. Either a model was requested that's available in an extra bundle, e.g. a widget, or a custom model was requested, but it wasn't registered before first usage.
```

I have not been able to figure out what is creating this error. I have previously been able to test the bokeh code in a Jupyter Notebook, and everything rendered as expected. I'm unsure what is breaking when I port it to Spyre.

Here is the code I'm testing below:

```
from spyre import server

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure

from bokeh.resources import INLINE, CDN
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, MultiSelect
import bokeh.models as bkm
from bokeh import palettes
from bokeh.io import vform

class SimpleApp(server.App):
    title = "Bokeh Test"
    inputs = [{ "type":"text",
                "key":"factor",
                "value":5,
                "label":"factor",
                "action_id":"line_plot"}]
    tabs=["Plot","Data"]
    outputs = [{"type":"html",
                "id":"bokeh_plot",
                "tab":"Plot",
                "control_id":"line_plot"},
                {"type":"table",
                "id":"bokeh_data",
                "tab":"Data",
                "control_id":"line_plot"}]
    controls = [{"type":"HIDDEN",
                 "id":"line_plot"}]
    def getHTML(self, params):
        df=self.getData(params)


        _tools_to_show = 'box_zoom,pan,save,resize,reset,tap,wheel_zoom'
        p=figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=600,x_axis_type='datetime',tools=_tools_to_show)

        colors=palettes.Spectral11
        colori=0

        #create source
        source_dict={}

        source_dict['Date']=df.index.format()
        for col in df.columns.tolist():
            source_dict['xaxis_'+col]=df.index.values
            source_dict['Date_'+col]=df.index.format()

            source_dict['yaxis_'+col]=df[col].values
            source_dict['yname_'+col]=np.tile(col, [len(df.index),1])

            source_dict['yaxisdup_'+col]=df[col].values

        source=ColumnDataSource(source_dict)

        #print source.data

        #source_dict={}
        for col in df.columns:
            #source= ColumnDataSource({'x': df.index.values, 'y': df[col].values, 'series_name': col, 'Date': df.index.format()})
            p.line('xaxis_'+col,'yaxis_'+col,source=source, legend=col,color=colors[colori],line_width=3)
            colori+=1



        colori=0
        scatlist=[]
        for col in df.columns.tolist():

            subdict = {'xaxis_'+col:source.data['xaxis_'+col], 'Date_'+col:source.data['Date_'+col], 'yname_'+col:source.data['yname_'+col],'yaxis_'+col:source.data['yaxis_'+col]}
            tempsource = ColumnDataSource(subdict)
            scat=p.scatter('xaxis_'+col, 'yaxis_'+col, source = source, fill_alpha=0, line_alpha=0.8, line_color=colors[colori],line_width=8)
            colori+=1
            scatlist.append(scat)
            g1_hover = bkm.HoverTool(renderers=[scat], tooltips=[("Series", "@yname_"+col), ("Date", "@Date_"+col),  ("Value", "@yaxis_"+col+"{0.00%}")])    
            g1_hover.mode='mouse'
            p.add_tools(g1_hover)



        p.background_fill_color='black'
        p.background_fill_alpha=0.9


        codestr="""
                var data = source.get('data');
                var f = cb_obj.get('value')

                cols="""+"['"+"','".join([col for col in df.columns.tolist()])+"']"+"""
                for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
                    if (f.indexOf(cols[i])> -1) {
                        data['yaxis_'+cols[i]]=data['yaxisdup_'+cols[i]]   
                    }
                    else {
                        data['yaxis_'+cols[i]]='nan'
                    }

                }
                source.trigger('change');
            """
        callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code=codestr)

        multi_select = MultiSelect(title="Lines to plot:", \
        value=df.columns.tolist(), \
        options=df.columns.tolist(), callback=callback)
        layout = vform(multi_select, p)

        script,div=components(layout,CDN)
        html = "%s\n%s"%(div, script)


        html='<center>'+html+'</center>'
        return html

    def getData(self,params):
        f=int(params['factor'])
        dr=pd.date_range('1-1-2010','12-31-2010',freq='D')
        vals=[i*f for i in range(len(dr))]
        df=pd.DataFrame(vals,index=dr,columns=['data'])

        return df
    def getCustomJS(self):
        return INLINE.js_raw[0]

    def getCustomCSS(self):
        css=INLINE.css_raw[0]
        return css
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = SimpleApp()
    app.launch()
```

SOLUTION:
Thanks to bigreddot for identifying this. I had to incorporate the widget js as well. My custom JS function now looks like this:

```
def getCustomJS(self):
    INLINE.js_raw[0]+INLINE.js_raw[1]
```

Comment: I think the problem is your `getCustomJS` function. BokehJS is a fairly large JS library. It was recently split up so that it's only necessary to "pay for" all the widget JS code if you actually use it. If you are using widgets. here is now a separate `bokeh-widgets.js` that has to be loaded, either inline, or from CDN. This is normally handled automatically, but it looks like you are overriding it to always only return the first block of `js_raw`, which means you are probably missing that necessary additional piece.

Comment: If Spyre limits you to returning a single string in that method, I suppose you could try concatenating all the pieces of `INLINE.js_raw` yourself. Alternatively, CDN resources might be easier.

Comment: I was unaware of the separation of bokeh-widgets.js. I'll see if I can work with that, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @bigreddot Adding in the second js attribute of js_raw fixed it! I'll edit with my solution. The getCustomJS function is an attribute of spyre's framework that it calls in the background. Spyre's example for implementing bokeh leverages that JS to make sure the bokeh JS gets in the right place in the application.

Comment: Great, I am glad that worked out! If you add that as an answer I will upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: Thanks to bigreddot for identifying this. I had to incorporate the widget js as well, as that is located in a separate script in js_raw. As Data Spyre has its own built in javascript functions you need to override, I ended up returning a concatenated string of the raw javascript elements in my function.

My custom JS function now looks like this:

```
def getCustomJS(self):
    INLINE.js_raw[0]+INLINE.js_raw[1]
```